# How to use ThreadLocal (specifically with Servlets)?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I have a web application that is using a framework where I have to implement an interface named Plot:

```
interface Plot {
  Image getImage();
  String getTitle();
}
```

I know the framework calls the `getImage()` before the `getTitle()`.  In some cases, I need the results from the image generation in order to create the title.

I know if I do something naive like this:

```
class MyNaivePlot implements Plot {
  private String title;

  public Plot getImage() {
    title = "...";
  }

  public String getTitle() { return title; }
}
```

Then I could introduce a race condition.  It seems I can fix this by using a `ThreadLocal` but I haven't seen enough examples to know if my solution is correct (and these sorts of things are hard to test with certainty).  So here's what I've come up with:

```
class MyThreadLocalPlot implements Plot {
  private ThreadLocal<String> title = new ThreadLocal<String>();

  public Plot getImage() {
    title.set("...");
  }

  public String getTitle() { 
    return title.get(); 
  }
}
```

Is this sufficient?  Am I using `ThreadLocal` correctly?  Note that I only need the title to hang around long enough until it is called for by `getTitle()`.  I don't care what it's value is after that nor before `getImage()` is called.

Also note that I believe the framework "long lives" the `MyPlot` object, and a new one isn't created for each request / thread, otherwise this would be a non-issue.

Thanks!

Comment: how is this class called ? is it instanciated for each request ? or just once ?

Comment: *Then I could introduce a race condition*: could you elaborate on this? How many instances of this class do you have? How are they created? How and why are they shared between threads?

Comment: your thread local variable should be static final

Comment: To chburd and JB: I thought I answered these in the post.  There is only one plot object that is shared between multiple threads / requests.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question - it sounds ok.
However, I would consider some additional points:

(1) If you have a hook for a beginning/end of request - you might want to clear the thread local at the end of each such request (e.g. if it's a servlet I'd use a filter). That's for two reasons: release it for the garbage collection, and for cases of errors (so that if the next request runs into some parsing error, it will see an empty image and not the previous user's).

(2) Make sure your framework indeed guarantees a single thread (and same machine) during those 2 requests. Perhaps also check if it's going to work on upcoming versions, and on horizontal scaling/clusters.

(3) As a side note, one might also consider other solutions - e.g. a cache (which would help you as a side effect). Obviously this requires some though as to cache size, periodical clearing/updating etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info; I can add a remove() to the end. And I am guaranteed both methods are called with the same thread.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You code is quite right; you don't have a setter method but I guess there is a typo and instead of `getImage` you want to write `setTitle()`.
threadLocal has also a `remove` method that you should invoke when you don't need the title attribute anymore. You could find some usage examples [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/threadlocal.html) and [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-thread-local-%E2%80%93-how-use)

Before deploying a ThreadLocal based version of Plot  I suggest you to check if your framework create one o or more instances; simply create a regolare class with a counter and increase the counter value in the get method; you can log it to see how the counter value changes with different calls. If you use a logging framework such as log4j or logback  I suggest to put the thread name in the log so you can check how/if the counter value changes with different checks.

I also suggest you to test it with multiple clients concurrently, if you have a "serial client" you may end up using always the same server thread if you are using a dedicated test instance.

Comment: Thanks, I will add a remove() in there.  And good advice about confirming that there is only one instance; I'm nearly certain this is the case.  As I mentioned, I have tried testing if my solution works but it's tricky as there are thread pools used.  It seemed to work correctly, but just wanted to confirm I wasn't missing anything.  Thanks again!